# Robovm connect to Gamecenter

Tags: java, robovm

I want to commit some Game Stats from my App to the Gamecenter. Have anyone ever worked with gamecenter and robovm? Is it possible to commit and receive data? If yes, how I do this?

best regards...

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the Game Kit framework to your Robovm.xml file in order to use Game Center.

You can take a look at this github code to understand how to implement it.

https://github.com/BlueRiverInteractive/robovm-ios-bindings/tree/master/gamecenter/src/org/robovm/bindings/gamecenter